# TransparentBlt Produces a Non-Sharp Image

Tags: .net, winapi, transparency, bitblt, bitblit

I'm rendering text (using `TextRenderer.DrawText`) onto a Bitmap which was back-colored solid White (`Color.White`) using the `FillRectangle` method.
I then `TransparentBlt` this Bitmap onto a memory-DC including a colorful background picture, using `Color.White And &HFFFFFF` as Transparent color's RGB value (`crTransparent` argument), as follows:

```
TransparentBlt(hDestMemDc, 0, 0, iTextWidth, iTextHeight, hTextMemDc, 0, 0, iTextWidth, iTextHeight, Color.White.ToArgb() And &HFFFFFF)
```

*{ I then `BitBlt` the combined image onto my control's surface, but that's not so relevant }*

**Whereas the rendered text is sharp and clear, its `TransparentBlt` result is *NOT* sharp.**

Here's a snapshot of the text, rendered over a White background (*this is an image and not typed text*):

[image]

And this is the result of Trans-Blitting the image above over a colorful background:

[image]

**Please notice that *white* (to-be-transparent) points are still surrounding the *red* text.**

Furthermore, notice the white vertical line drawn to the left of the image, and the similar shorter horizontal line drawn at the top-right corner.

**I'm using VB.NET 2005 (a.k.a VB8). Your advice would be very appreciated.**

Comment: Looks like font smoothing. How are you rendering the text?

Comment: oGraphics.CompositingQuality = Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
        oGraphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
        oGraphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
        oGraphics.TextContrast = 0
        oGraphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias

Comment: `Dim sRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, m_sTextSize.Width, m_sTextSize.Height)`

`Dim oBrush As Brush = New SolidBrush(const_sTextBackColor)`        `oGraphics.FillRectangle(oBrush, sRect)`
`TextRenderer.DrawText(oGraphics, Me.Text, Me.Font, sRect, Me.ForeColor, const_sTextBackColor, m_eTextFormatFlags)`

If this is indeed the cause, how is rendering's result (upper image) is sharp?

Answer (score 2):

Text anti-aliasing / ClearType means that not all of your text is rendered in the same colour. The outside pixels of the text are blended with the background colour over which they're drawn, which has the effect of smoothing the edges. Because of this, you can't render text on one background colour, clip it out, and expect it to look as good against another background.

You can disable anti-aliasing when you render the text, but the results will not look that good either.

Instead, you should make a copy of the final target bitmap in memory, render the text over that, and then blit it back to the screen again.

Comment: First - thanks for the educative answer. It is obliged. I did not mention the application of this, which is a text scroller. I'm using blitting as a more CPU-efficient approach. If I would have to render the text every 20[mSec] one pixel up, I'd lose the CPU-consumption benefits of blitting (and I tried). Any ideas?

Comment: You could try using a transparent window (i.e one created with `WS_EX_LAYERED` and updated with `UpdateLayeredWindow`) and then render the text directly to that, but you would still need to re-draw the text every time. Or try two layered windows, both the width of the screen - and then move the windows themselves to get the scroll effect, but again I don't know if that would be any better in terms of CPU usage.

Comment: Is a (CPU-usage) performance-difference expected between text-rendering within the `OnPaint` event-handler-function (indirectly invoked by calling `Refresh()` on every timer tick), and text-rendering within the timer-tick handler-function itself (which afterwards also blitts the result to control's surface)?

Comment: Probably not dramatically, `OnPaint` may be slightly less as `WM_PAINT` messages are only dispatched when no other messages are in the queue but in reality there won't be much difference.

Comment: I've formed a memory-DC (using `CreateCompatibleDC`) onto which I'm blitting the background image. I would now like to try you suggestion to render the text on top of it (and then blit the combined image to control surface). How could the `TextRenderer.DrawText` function be used with a memory-DC? Its 1st argument is of `System.Drawing.IDeviceContext` type, whereas the memory-DC is of `IntPtr` type.

Comment: I'm guessing you'd have to start with a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` rather than calling the raw Win32 functions, but I don't really know anything about .NET I'm sorry.